# Getting index of item in partition function

Tags: rust

I need to split an array/vector in rust and found [partition](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.partition) in the document. It looks like the callback function passed to `partition` only has access to items of the array. How do I get the index of the item?

For example, giving an array `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, how do I split it into two based on their position so the first one would be `[1, 3]` because each of them has an even position(1 and 3 has index 0 and 2 which is an even number) and the second would be `[2, 4]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution could be to use [`enumerate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate) and [`partition_map`](https://docs.rs/itertools/*/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.partition_map) from itertools:

```
use itertools::{Either, Itertools};

fn main() {
    let a = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];

    let (b, c): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = a.into_iter().enumerate().partition_map(|(i, foo)| {
        if i % 2 == 0 {
            Either::Left(foo)
        } else {
            Either::Right(foo)
        }
    });

    println!("{:?}, {:?}", b, c);
}
```

Comment: Minor comment: would be nice to split the iterator chain into multiple lines to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

To get the index while iterating over an `Iterator` you can use [`Iterator::enumerate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate).

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let (a, b): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = arr.iter().enumerate().partition(|(i, _)| i % 2 == 0);
```

The problem is to "unenumerate" the vector. For this you can use this function:

```
fn unenumerate<T>(a: impl IntoIterator<Item = (usize, T)>) -> Vec<T> {
    a.into_iter().map(|(_, e)| e).collect()
}
```

Combined it will let you get the desired result:

```
println!("{:?} {:?}", unenumerate(a), unenumerate(b)); // [1, 3] [2, 4]
```

Comment: I don't like this solution if you are stuck with only std I would use a mutable state: https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=40f94b06743f016b0d3d26230f339ded (or implement partition_map yourself ofc)